# When do we create IBOutlet ViewController objects in it's AppDelegate?

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, viewcontroller, appdelegate

First of all let me mention I am new to IOS development.

Generally when we create a new project in XCODE, there is no object declared like

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
```

in the automatically created `AppDelegate.h`.
And still most of the custom views created and added as subview to the main view works fine.

But in sub application it is needed to declare the object of our view controller as mentioned above. And has to be added to `window`'s subview in `AppDelegate.m`, like this:

```
    [window addSubview:viewcontroller.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Otherwise, some controller's view e.g., `MPMediaPlayerController.view`(in my case),etc could not be properly added as subview to the `viewController`'s view.

Why does this happen?

And in which cases do we need to declare the view controller's object in delegate class?

Answer (score 0):

There are different answers depending on what Xcode version you're using and how you're defining your interface but, assuming something recent with a storyboard, the answer is that it's happening during the loading of your initial controller.

For a view controller to be used, something needs to retain it and the window's `rootViewController` is the initial default.  If you look in the documentation for "Configuring the Initial View Controller at Launch", you'll see some steps listed:

> "[...] iOS performs the following actions:
>
> ...
>
> It sets the window’s rootViewController property to the new view
>   controller."